# Logout for Dot Net Core and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

We currently have two applications and they are pointing to the same database. Say App1 which is developed in ASP.NET. This is a legacy application. App2 is a new application built in .Net Core. Both applications are being hosted on the same server. Users can only navigate from App2 (new) to App1 (old). Users can only log in from App2. When a user logs on to App2, a cookie "app2Cookie" is set on client-side. App2 has a link to navigate to App1. When a user clicks on this link, he will be able to land on App1. App1 creates its own session "App1Session". Now ask is if the user logs out from App2, it should get logged out from App1 as well. The problem is when user logs out app2Cookie is cleared from the client browser but not sure how to clear app1Session on the server.

Comment: From app1, check for the app2 cookie (assuming they share the same domain). If it’s not there, end the app1session.

Comment: They do share the same domain. Is it possible to check for app2 cookie from app1? Can you share some example or forum that can help? Also, on app1, we do not have complete access to the source code (it is a custom application created using third party tool). So, all we have to do is using Request Handlers.

Comment: I’m sure there are plenty of questions about how to read a cookie from asp.net around... `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies`, likely. If I’m not mistaken, you have access to `HttpContext` from a handler.